# Does PPO's gradient clipping really prevent r(θ) from exceeding 1±epsilon?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

When updating the policy in PPO, does the clipping part stop the weights at the exact value for which r(θ) is exactly 1±epsilon or does it allow to exceed that value and then prevent it from going any further by setting the gradient to zero? Which one is what is actually going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > or does it allow to exceed that value and then prevent it from going any further by setting the gradient to zero?

This is exactly what it does. The clipping term in PPO cannot prevent r(θ) from moving beyond 1±ε, but after it exceeds it, the gradient will be zero and r(θ) will effectively be ignored by backpropagation.

Keep in mind, however, that this is all happening simultaneously with experiences from other timesteps; this means it's possible for r(θ) at time t to move back into the 1±ε region, at which point it will start getting updated again.

The end result is that |1-r(θ)| will be roughly (but not exactly) bounded by ε at all timesteps.